# django models error when inputting form data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

[Full Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6WOb.png)

I am a beginner in django, and am having some trouble inputting form data to database. I am getting a

```
`TypeError at /Info/
Info() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'`
```

when I feel I am doing it correctly
Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Info(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
```

My Views.py

```
def Info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            Facts = Info(email = email)
            Facts.save()
        else:
            form = InfoForm()
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title': 'Info'})



def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title': 'Home'})
```

My Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class InfoForm(forms.Form):
   address = forms.CharField()
   email = forms.EmailField()
```

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the impression that you do too much work here yourself. If you use a `ModelForm`, you can avoid constructing an `Info` yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome that you are trying out something new, Django is an excellent framework and I hope you learn lots. So a couple of things I've noticed in your code that may help. So the reason you are having that error in particular is because you have a clash in your naming. You use Info as your class name and also for your view. Functions should typically be lower-cased. So if you look below, this should resolve your error. But I agree with the comment posted earlier that you perhaps look into ModelForm https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

```
from wherever.models import Info
from wherever.forms import InfoForm

def info_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            facts = Info(email=email, address=address)
            facts.save()
        else:
            form = InfoForm()
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title': 'Info'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Info` function has the same name as a model, so it shadows the name of the model.

Try something more like this

```
def save_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            Facts = Info(email = email)
            Facts.save()
        else:
            form = InfoForm()
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title': 'Info'})
```

That said, you can simplify this quite a bit; `ModelForm` instances have a `save` function that can be called as if it were a model object:

```
def save_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            # report an appropriate error
            print("something went wrong!")
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'title': 'Info'})
```